# UML Notation - one or more of optional

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I am using Enterprise Architect to create a class model showing an object A which has an optional association with a single instance of three objects B, C & D i.e. A---->B (0..1), A----->C (0...1), A-----> D (0..1).

The problem is that I want to be able to say that collectively A must have at least 1 instance of B Or C Or D.  And to make things tricky, I cant just create a generalisation above B,C,D (lets call it X) and link A to that generalisation with a 1...*, because I am generating an XSD from the model in Enterprise Architect.  The XSD then says any XML weith A as an element must contain X as a sub element (rather than saying B AND/OR C AND/OR D).

I am thinking there is some clever way to join the three associations from A to B,C and D toghether to say at least one of those associations must exist, without having to create a generalisation X above B, C & D.

Answer (score 6):

In UML, relationships are mainly between two elements, so it's difficult to achieve what you're after. The generalization construct you describe is the normal solution for this.

You can also add a constraint and link it to the connectors. This will inform a human reader, but EA won't care. I'm pretty sure that even if you write the constraint in OCL (the formal constraint language), EA won't evaluate it during the generation process.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it makes sense.  The only possible route I can think of, then, is to try and add xpath into the XSD to enforce the constraint, or just have a separate xpath job after the XSD validation to enforce the more complex relational rules.

Comment: I'm afraid so. If you were generating source code for one of the languages EA supports you could modify the generation templates, but XSD generation is a separate function with no user-servicable parts inside.